# Tkinter search / filter bar - csv file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, listbox

referring to http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578860-setting-up-a-listbox-filter-in-tkinterpython-27/ Is there a way to do this but with 2 or more listboxes? For example: A first and last name listbox. I Have tried to do this however it searches both columns individually when I want them to be linked.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more regarding the actual problem ?

Comment: I want to search for a specific result in a CSV file using an entry label. The two columns are first and last name. This is shown in the link provided in the question, however this is only for the first name, I want it to work for first and last name. When I tried to do this it searches both first and last names, this means the results shown are not linked (first and last name do not match). Is there a way to one search the first name and display results so they are still linked (the first and last name are next to each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your problem right, you wont something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

# First create application class


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.lbox_list = [('Adam', 'Mitric' ),
                           ('Lucy', 'Devic'  ), 
                           ('Bob' , 'Freamen'), 
                           ('Amanda', 'Ling' ), 
                           ('Susan', 'Cascov')]

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    # Create main GUI window
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.search_var = StringVar()
        self.search_var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self.update_list())
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.search_var, width=13)
        self.lbox1 = Listbox(self, width=20, height=15)
        self.lbox2 = Listbox(self, width=20, height=15)         # Second List Box. Maybe you can use treeview ? 

        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.lbox1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.lbox2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        # Function for updating the list/doing the search.
        # It needs to be called here to populate the listbox.
        self.update_list()

    def update_list(self):
        search_term = self.search_var.get()

        # Just a generic list to populate the listbox

        self.lbox1.delete(0, END)
        self.lbox2.delete(0, END)       # Deletng from second listbox

        passed = []                     # Need this to check for colisions

        for item in self.lbox_list:
            if search_term.lower() in item[0].lower():
                self.lbox1.insert(END, item[0])
                self.lbox2.insert(END, item[1])
                passed.append(item)

        for item in self.lbox_list:
            if search_term.lower() in item[1].lower() and item not in passed:
                self.lbox1.insert(END, item[0])
                self.lbox2.insert(END, item[1])


root = Tk()
root.title('Filter Listbox Test')
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```